# Unable to find Multi Store Links in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

I am new to Magento. I have installed `FreeGo` theme in my Magento 2.3.x and I've created Multi Stores in Admin Panel but how can I view them? I am unable to find links to view them. Not in the footer, not in the admin panel. Can you please tell me how can I view those stores I have created? Where are the links...
**Here is the screenshot:**
[image]
**Please help me**

**UPDATE:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme layout folder you can found `default.xml` for check on frontend add below code before `body` tag.

```
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header.panel" before="header.links" />
```

Default magento luma theme path is below: 
\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Theme\layout

Comment: Luma theme has already `store switcher/selector` in footer by default but I have changed theme to `FreeGo` theme, Here i searched **default.xml** but there are a lot of files names with this

Comment: Yes, Luma theme have default but you need to define in your theme XML file if it's not showing. you can go "app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego\Magento_Theme\layout" in this folder you will found 'default.xml'

Comment: Hey, worked. Path was `magento\app\design\frontend\Solwin\freego\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`, and I have updated my question, you can see updated screenshot, how my store switcher is showing, can it be done in nice thing? or can it move to the right like before that message `default welcome message`?

Comment: update before="welcome.message" like this.
<move element="store_switcher" destination="header.panel" before="welcome.message" />

Comment: Worked, Thanks a lot @Sangeeta

Comment: I have multi stores, so can it be like this that every store can have different products ? And If main store want to give products to their child store (one or more) then main store can give them, then that products will be added to those child stores (selected by main store)

Comment: you can do by enable/disabled products by store view wise or create products by website wise.

Comment: Can i create different product for specific store?

Comment: Store is a part of website that is used to manage categories, as well as their display on the frontend. Pricing, taxes, default currency, payments, shipping, products, customers, orders are managed by website wise.

Comment: Actually, It's my office work. I am not a magento developer and personally I don't like magento , but my boss forced me to create website in magento, and said that We have plan like this:  **1 main store, and that main store will have child stores, then it's our choice that products will be different or same in stores and we (Main store) can give their child store stock products**